# Sending emails from frontend, triggered by a cronjob (using NightwatchJS?)

Tags: javascript, cron, nightwatch.js

I have a WordPress-page, that sends a bunch of data to a JS-frontend (written in Vue). In the frontend, a whole bunch of calculations are made and are presented to the viewer.

Now, I would like to send those information in an email, triggered by a cron-job (so the email could be sent every day or every other day, at specific times).

But I'm not sure how to set this up. Because the frontend need to render, in order to to see the product of the calculations.

I thought about setting up [NightwatchJS](http://nightwatchjs.org/) and [smptjs](https://www.smtpjs.com/), but I haven't used either of those three; so I'm worried if I can even do what I'm attempting. ... Or if it would work well (not be buggy).

Is that the best way to send emails automatically from a frontend JS-application on a daily basis, or are there a better way?

Comment: I would just put an endpoint on your server for storing the underlying data the frontend calculates and send that asynchronously right before you display it or whatever. Then you have a cron on the server that queries/aggregates/etc. Don't know what the other stuff is for, or if doing an SMTP to a mailbox in a browser session is too wise, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: But doesn't that mean, that the data (that should be sent), would be generated and saved upon every page load? ... Ideally, is should only be generated once; just before the cron-job executes.

Comment: Then use a url variable to trigger the frontend script to send it back to the server, and only use that when your cronjob hits it.